# tag [data-storage] should be a synonym of [storage]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose making these tags synonymous, unless there is some difference between them that I can't think of. Looking at the questions associated with each, it is clear that the users see these two tags as the same.

What do people think? Any objections?

Answer (score 0):

Seems legit. I do not see a case that they mean something different.

Currently they are used as the following.

```
data-storage x 11
storage x 19
```

I will add a synonym, when no one has an objection.